# What is a .dhtml page?

Tags: dhtml

What is a .dhtml page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DHTML is a TERM describing the art of making dynamic and interactive web pages.

<sub>From the Tag excerpt from Stackoverflow</sub> <sup>*[[Read]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dhtml/info)*</sup>

> Dynamic HTML, or DHTML, is an umbrella term for a collection of technologies used together to create interactive and animated web sites by using a combination of a static markup language (such as HTML), a client-side scripting language (such as JavaScript), a presentation definition language (such as CSS), and the Document Object Model.

For more information, You can check out these links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/default.asp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML

Answer (score 2):

DHTML, is a term for a collection of technologies used together to create interactive and animated web sites by using a combination of a static markup language (such as HTML), a client-side scripting language (such as JavaScript), a presentation definition language (such as CSS), and the Document Object Model.

Comment: this is copy & paste answer taken from wikipedia, right?  http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dynamic_HTML&oldid=360881970

Comment: nothing wrong with that. one time i posted some copy paste from the perl doc and got 16 up votes (i did cite)